# Flotr Chart Displaying White Page

Tags: html, graph, charts, flotr

I am using flotr chart javascript libary. when i Create basic_axis chart from the above link it showing me the white page

http://www.solutoire.com/experiments/flotr/examples/basic-axis.html

Hear is the sample code , i am new for flotr javascript.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/Navya/7WGkZ/
```

Comment: you should add the flotr library to the jsfiddle example

Comment: For me even in  Html page displaying the same, Can u please explain me in detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is your example working : http://jsfiddle.net/7WGkZ/1/

you have to add this in the "head":

```
<head>
... 
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/HumbleSoftware/Flotr2/master/flotr2.min.js"></script>
...
</head>
```